# Etymology of 'motet'

Tags: étymologie, noms, musique

This word is by definition *a short piece of choral music* and a word of French origin according to the etymology section on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/motet#English). Although it is not stated specifically if `motet` falls under the category of [Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_French), [Modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_language) or [Old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_French) French. It can be used and spoken by native speakers today but to which time and form of the French language is it best attributed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/motet) gives everything you are looking for:

> **Étymol. et Hist.** 1. Fin XII<sup>e</sup>s. «petit mot» (*Orson de Beauvais*, 532 ds T.-L.: un sol **motet** sonner) rare, cependant encore attesté au XVII<sup>e</sup>s. (Carloix ds Littré). 2. ca 1270 «petit poème, (d'inspiration religieuse ou non) destiné à être chanté, à deux, trois ou quatre parties distinctes» (Rutebeuf, *La desputoison de Challot et du Barbier ds Œuvres*, éd. E. Faral et J.Bastin, t.2, p.264); 3. 1680 «morceau de musique composé sur des paroles religieuses, destiné à être exécuté à l'église, sans faire partie de l'office divin» (Rich.). Diminutif de [*mot*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mot)* à l'aide du suffixe [*-et*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-et)*.

So *motet* was already there in Old French (12th century) and is a diminutive of *mot* (word), kind of similar to "wordlet". I should add that I hadn't heard about that word before your question.